# Apache2 SSL configuration - apache always chooses the first ip-based virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

We have an Ubuntu 10.04 server running Apache 2.2.14 with 4 ip-based virtual hosts. We have 2 ip addresses and a ssl cert for each ip address. ex:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:443> -> SSL 1

<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:80>
<VirtualHost 2.2.2.2:4443> -> SSL 2
```

No matter what we do, for some reason, Apache will always find the first virtual host included but not the second when serving https requests. This results in apache serving the ssl cert from the first vhost included for BOTH ipaddress. A very undesirable result.

All of the ip address configurations are correct. Running `apache2ctl -S` says that all configurations are correct.

We do not use any name-based virtual hosts.

It does not matter which :443 vhost is included first, apache will only serve the cert from the first vhost included.

It is our understanding that apache will default to using the first vhost that it finds as the default if it does not find a virtual host for the ip address:port.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Post the output of `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`.

Comment: Are the IP addresses correctly attached to the server, or do you have a private ip address on your server that they route to?

Comment: In order to get this setup working for the moment, we changed the second vhost:443 do to _default_:443. Here is the link to the output of the command above -> http://pastebin.com/p6AamHcz

Comment: The .235 vhost works fine and is not included in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Apache2 requires the `ServerName` directive for all `<VirtualHost>`s. Our two SSL vhosts were ending up having the same `ServerName` and one would end up being the default for both IP addresses.